# How to assign a callback function to a state variable in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm working on a React component and I have a state variable called myStateDrawer, which is represented by a callback function. I want to update the state by assigning a new value to this callback function whenever a certain event occurs.

Here's the code snippet illustrating the situation:

`<MyComponent customOverride={(newValue) => { this.state.myStateDrawer() = newValue; }} />`

However, this code throws an error stating "Invalid left-hand side in assignment". I'm not sure how to correctly assign the new value to the myStateDrawer callback function within the customOverride prop.

Can someone please guide me on how to properly assign a callback function to a state variable in this scenario? I want to update the state using the customOverride prop by setting a new value for the myStateDrawer callback function.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Ultimately the goal is to:

Assign a callback function to a state variable in React by utilizing setState within the customOverride prop. The state variable represents the callback function, and it needs to be updated and accessed correctly. An intermediary state might be required to store the callback function and provide access to it within a separate myDrawerState function.

It's supposed to do a certain action once the state gets passed into the customOverride.

Comment: What's the not working part in your question ? Also are you using Class based Components ?

Comment: It won’t accept this.state.myDrawer and yes it’s using class components.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.